# How can I convert floating point values in text to binary using Perl?

Tags: perl

I have text file looks like that:

```
float a[10] = {
    7.100000e+000 ,
    9.100000e+000 ,
    2.100000e+000 ,
    1.100000e+000 ,
    8.200000e+000 ,
    7.220000e+000 ,
    7.220000e+000 ,
    7.222000e+000 ,
    1.120000e+000 ,
    1.987600e+000
};

unsigned int col_ind[10] = {
    1 ,
    4 ,
    3 ,
    4 ,
    5 ,
    2 ,
    3 ,
    4 ,
    1 ,
    5
};
```

Now, I want to convert each array (float / unsigned int) to different binary files - [big endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) type, a binary file for all float values and a binary file for all integer values.

What is the simple way to do it in Perl, consider I have over two millon elements in each array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to look into [`binmode`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode.html) and [`pack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html). Here's an example that might get you started. I'm not sure I've chosen the pack templates that you need, but see the `pack` documentation for all of the choices.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($fh, $pack_template);

while (my $line = <>){
    if ( $line =~ /(float|int)/ ){
        $pack_template = $1 eq 'int' ? 'i' : 'f';

        undef $fh;
        open $fh, '>', "$1.dat" or die $!;
        binmode $fh;

        next;
    }

    next unless $line =~ /\d/;
    $line =~ s/[,\s]+$//;

    print $fh pack($pack_template, $line);
}
```